# Account for timezone when comparing Unix Timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In wordpress, I am storing a date as a Unix timestamp.

So, today would be stored as 1411344000 (2014/22/09). Basically, I want to get today's date as a UNIX timestamp and then I plan on doing some comparisons with wp_query.

I am doing something like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date1 = date('Y/m/d');
$date2 = strtotime($date1);
```

And then I use $date2 for the comparison with my stored timestamp. This works for most of the day except it doesn't take into account my timezone that is PST . So, around 4PM (PST) all my date comparisons become off. I am not sure how to account for this 8 hour time difference properly and I get confused trying to wrap my mind around it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Store dates as `date` presumably, instead of `int`

Comment: Why don't you set the default timezone to your timezone instead of UTC?

Comment: The timestamp being stored is based on epoch. Basically, I want to be able to match the stored unix timestamp with  date() that is then passed to strtotime() for today's timestamp. I have read other posts that mention you need to manually minus the time difference, but I am but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX timestamp already uniquely identifies the time - it does not depend on timezone. So if you have UNIX timestamp in database, just compare it to current UNIX timestamp (`time()`).

Depending on what you want to do, you can compare just these integers (to get difference in seconds for example) or make `\DateTime` or string representing date from them.

If you want to check if the current date matches the saved one, you should specify timezone in which you want the dates to be calculated.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
var_dump(date('Y-m-d') === date('Y-m-d', $timestampFromDb));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I working in Wordpress/wp_query and need to compare a set value that is a timestamp of a date with 0 hours and 0 seconds. So, 09/22/2014 will be 1411344000. What I really need to do is get today's timestamp with 0 hours and 0 seconds referencing the timezone. Then store it in a variable. Possible?

Comment: `$date = new DateTime('today 00:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC')); $var = $date->getTimestamp();` or `date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); $var = strtotime('today 00:00');`

Comment: Thanks. This is closer. But still not accounting for timezone the way it looks like it should and I am not sure why. Right now it is 5:14 PST. Before 5PM $var equaled 1411344000, which is what I want. After PM it changes to tomorrows value. I tried to change date_default_timezone to America/Los_Angeles but that did not work. It outputs to 1411369200 .